# How to count if the cell value has either "Open" or "In Progress"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to count if the cell has either "Open" or "In Progress", used below function and it's not worked

```
=Counifs(Range,OR("Open","In Progress")
```

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTIF(Range,"Open")+COUNTIF(Range,"In Progress")`